# Adding a picture to Rally artifact by using Pyral

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I have been trying to add pictures in a Test Case in Rally by using Pyral.

I have been able to successfully add the attachment and the link to the picture.

However, the picture is not displayed:

[image: Incorrect image]

When I download the picture from the attachments, it is a 1 kB picture (while it should be 37 kB) and cannot be opened.

I am using the following code
code

```
    TCID = "TC1234"
    attachment = rally.addAttachment(TCid, "picture_new.jpg", mime_type="image/jpeg")
    Step['ExpectedResult']='Test picture<br /><img src="/slm/attachment/{oid}/{Name}" />'.format(**attachment.__dict__)
    list_Steps.append(Step)
    #... and some code to update the Test Steps in the Test Case that works fine
```

The following code works fine with a text file (the attached file has the correct size and content) but not for the picture.

Is it something wrong in my code or in the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the way the Rest API read the content from the file

```
#extract from function addAttachment in file 'restapi.py'
with open(filename, 'r') as af:
    contents = base64.b64encode(af.read())
```

This works fine for text files but not for binary files.

A temporary solution is to patch function `addAttachment` of `restapi.py` by reading the file as binary `open(filename, 'rb')`, which would work as well for text files.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as af:
    contents = base64.b64encode(af.read())
```

And that worked fine for me afterwards:
[image: Correct import of picture]

**Note**: On my computer (Windows), the file `restapi.py` can be found in:

> *{Python Install dir}*/Lib/site-packages/pyral/restapi.py